# How to make a query based in other table values?, one query for each unique value of another table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables "devices", "data", and "variables" as shown down below:

```
Devices table

|dev_id  | serialnumber | 
|--------|--------------|
|1       | 123546       |
|2       | 456879       |
|3       | 789456       |
 .          .
 .          . 
 .          . 


variables table

|var_id  | name         | 
|--------|--------------|
|1       | BAT          |
|2       | TEMPERATURE  |
|3       | PRES         |
 .          .
 .          . 
 .          . 


Data table

|id  | dev_id  | var_id | value | timestmp            | 
|----|---------|--------|-------| --------------------|
|1   | 1       | 1      | 15    |  2019-08-16 19:38:28|
|2   | 1       | 2      | 30    |  2019-08-16 19:38:28|
|3   | 1       | 3      | 101005|  2019-08-16 19:38:28|
|4   | 2       | 1      | 18    |  2019-08-16 20:39:28|
|5   | 2       | 2      | 50    |  2019-08-16 20:39:28|
|6   | 1       | 1      | 60    |  2019-08-16 22:20:28|
|7   | 3       | 1      | 18    |  2019-08-16 22:39:28|
|8   | 2       | 1      | 65    |  2019-08-16 20:39:28|
 .     .         .        .         .
 .     .         .        .         .
 .     .         .        .         .
```

I want to retrieve from data the lasts value of each dev_id for specific var_id.
but I didn't find the way to do that in a query or transaction.

I need something like this for var_id = 1

```
| id  | dev_id | var_id | value | timestmp |
|-----|--------|--------|-------|----------|
|8    | 2      | 1      |  65   | ......   |
|7    | 3      | 1      |  18   | ......   |
|6    | 1      | 1      |  60   | ......   |
```

Comment: Please _delete_ the screen captures and instead include all that information as _text_, formatted as code, with each line having four or more spaces in front of it.

Comment: Or go a step further... See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What do you mean by "the lasts value of each dev_id"

Comment: @MarkOverton the last value recorded for dev_id = 1, the last value recorder for dev_id = 2, and so on (for each dev_id in devices table)

Comment: by 'last value' do you mean the 'serialnumber'?

Comment: By the last values I refer to the last record for each different dev_id in data table (that should be in devices table too)

Comment: I don't think you are making much sense - the example you have provided, I have recreated that result with the second query in my answer. You've mentioned you want to do the same for devices, which my first query does. I'm not sure what else you need, can you try explaining it another way?

Comment: Hi again  @MarkOverton . First of all, thanks yo for you patience. I will try to explain in other words. I want to retrieve the last **same var_id** for **each dev_id**. So the query must give one result for each unique dev_id. In the example given, 3 results, one for dev_id = 1, one for dev_id = 2 and one for dev_id = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from data t
where 
t.var_id = 1
and
not exists (
  select 1 from data
  where dev_id = t.dev_id and var_id = t.var_id and timestamp > t.timestamp
)
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot! this is the kind of query I was looking for. Can you explain this query in words to better understanding? Thanks you :)

Comment: NOT EXISTS makes sure that for the returned rows there are not other rows with greater date. This means that the returned rows contain the last date for each device and var_id. In your sample data though there are 2 rows for the same device and var_id=1 with the same date. In this case both rows will be returned.

Comment: Thanks you a lot :) have a nice day

Comment: Working, but too slow when there is multiple records in the database

Comment: Set indexes on the columns var_id, dev_id and timestamp.

Comment: This subquery "not exists (select 1 from data
  where dev_id = t.dev_id and var_id = t.var_id and timestamp > t.timestamp)" makes the query working slow, I found a better solution, using "ts = (SELECT MAX(ts) FROM data WHERE dev_id = t.dev_id AND var_id = t.var_id)" instead

Answer (score 0):

**Get the most recent record from devices:**

```
SELECT d.* FROM devices de 
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.dev_id = de.dev_id 
WHERE de.dev_id = 1 
ORDER BY d.timestmp DESC
```

**Get the most recent record from variables:**

```
SELECT d.* FROM variables v 
LEFT JOIN data d ON d.var_id = v.var_id 
WHERE v.var_id = 1 
ORDER BY d.timestmp DESC
```

Comment: I had new info for clear understanding of my question

Comment: I've updated my answer - is this more what you were looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to do that in a single query or transaction

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on your question, I don't think we fully understand what you mean to accomplish.